# How to mount an NFS share with rootless Podman?

Tags: mount, nfs, podman, rootless

How can I mount the NFS share *mynfsserver.example.com:/path/to/share*
when running rootless Podman?

I'm running the latest released Podman as of today (8 January 2022).

```
$ podman --version
podman version 3.4.4
$
```

Linux kernel version is **5.15.12**.

```
$ uname -r
5.15.12-200.fc35.x86_64
$
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update 2022-05-31

I'm not sure this answer is correct.
I also asked a [question](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/13982) about this in the discussion forum in the Podman Github repo.

---

#### Old answer

Support for rootless mounting of an NFS share
is now supported in Podman if you are running the very latest development branches of Podman and the Linux kernel.

To mount an NFS share when running rootless Podman:

`podman volume create --opt type=nfs --opt o=async --opt device=mynfsserver.example.com:/path/to/share`

Unfortunately it will take a bit of time before support lands in the official packages. (**Podman 3.4.4** and **Linux 5.15.12** does not have support)

References:

Podman chat channel messages 6 January 2022:

[*Rootless mounting of NFS just got merged into upstream kernel*](https://matrix.to/#/!SEjxdEhDPWoPxzjWCX:matrix.org/$cSLcD0ZEwHLjo0hEAjlVuh1AIKJlwzuQgW39zLHytZs?via=matrix.org&via=libera.chat&via=t2bot.io)

[*podman volume create --opt type=nfs --opt o=async --opt device=mynfsserver:/path/to/share
21:49
neat that it works rootless now*](https://matrix.to/#/!SEjxdEhDPWoPxzjWCX:matrix.org/$TGOvx5IcbWYXmgT4p5NkM8nnETk92-pPrGgeulI51wE?via=matrix.org&via=libera.chat&via=t2bot.io)

Comment: Can you copy the content at those links please? If you don't have matrix set up, it's really diffiicult to access the content.

Comment: I added some text from the chat. Unfortunately, I haven't got it to work myself, although I haven't tried much.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly. I can mount an NFS directory that's already mounted on the host file system with

```
podman run --runtime=/usr/bin/crun --group-add=keep-groups --volume=/storage/nfs/outside_dir:/in_container_dir --storage-driver overlay --storage-opt "overlay.mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs" --userns=keep-id -it registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi
```

Comment: The tricky part is mounting NFS in the first place (as a non-root user). I'm not sure it's possible.